# How use IBDesignable class in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibdesignable

I'm a beginner in `Swift` and `Xcode`, and I want to know what is the practice to use the `IBDesignable` class in a `UITableView`. I design the card in my class for directly see the result in my storyboard but I have some label, UIImage and other component that I need to modify dynamically in a `UITableView` in this function :

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell

    let cardData: Card
    cardData = self.card[indexPath.row]

    // Here I want to catch the card what I design in the class IBDesignableCard to set the IBDesignableCard.label, IBDesignableCard.userImage ...

    return cell // And here return the IBDesignableCard
    }
```

How can I achieve that ? Thanks you for your reply.

Comment: In my limited experience, IBDesignable is a way to customise UI Elements offered in the first instance by the I.B. (InterfaceBuilderDesignable, not in-codeDesignable ) like giving buttons or labels a rounded border of a certain thickness. Ray Wenderlich's site has a good tutorial. Its easier to do than have it explained. I know you are asking about the elements that make up a Tableview, but you have to write the specification from a separate class file. What have you searched for so far? perhaps you should that add to your question. Welcome to SO and the world of Swift.

Comment: @aremvee Thanks to your reply! Yes what I want is to preview my design in the storyboard and dynamically modify what I build in the IBDesign class but apparently my only way is to build my card directly in a 'normal' class and call it in the tableView function.